# Структура БД в приложении типа Instagram

Tags: sql, instagram, нормализация-данных

Делаю приложение по типу *Instagram.* Есть две таблицы: пользователи и фото.

**Вопросы:**

- В каком виде и куда записывать лайки пользователя, чтобы делать выборку всех лайкнутых фото?
- В каком виде и куда записывать пользователей, лайкнувших фото, чтобы делать выборку всех лайкнувших пользователей?

У меня два предположения:

1. Массивы внутри столбцов лайки и массив в столбце лайкнувшие в соответствующих таблицах.
2. Создавать отдельную таблицу на каждого пользователя и на каждое фото.

Оба варианта мне кажутся неверными, но опыта не хватает сообразить как правильно.

Comment: На каждую сущность должна быть своя таблица. Есть пользователи, фотки и лайки - 3 сущности. Значит, делаем три таблицы. Если добавлются, например, понятия "друзья", "подписчики" - делаем таблицы и для этих сущностей. При этом, если связь многие-ко-многим, то и дополнительные таблицы для этих связей нужны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый нормальный вариант (как в смысле
[нормализации данных](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D0%B0),
так и в смысле «не-ненормальный») — это таблица
связей.  Пример для *PostgreSQL*:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS photos (
  photo_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, file TEXT
-- …
)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS users (
  user_id BIGINT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY
, login TEXT
-- …
)
;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS likes (
  photo_id BIGINT REFERENCES photos(photo_id)
, user_id BIGINT REFERENCES users(user_id)
-- …
)
;
```

Comment: Нужен ли индекс для таблицы likes? Поиск в этой таблице будет происходить, как по фото, так и по пользователям.

Comment: Да, разумеется.  ЕМНИП, `REFERENCES` индексы автоматом не добавляет.